What alternative modes do I have to get from Pittsburgh to Denver?
I am traveling with a bike.  I am not considering biking there ...
The obvious options are Amtrak, Greyhound, fly, or drive.  A direct flight is about $400 round-trip depending on the exact travel dates which is fair.  Amtrak is about $1200 and 33 hours, Greyhound is about $240 for 34 hours, and driving would end up at about $400 for fuel and 20 hours of driving not to mention parking once I get there.
Is there any sort of website that caters to cyclists that might run a bus separately from Greyhound or anything like that?

When I enter those cities in the Amtrak website it finds me fares for $320 each way.

It does depend on how soon you want to go, but yes, Amtrak is expensive and slow.

Take a look at Rome2Rio.

Amtrak from Pittsburgh to Denver, leaving tomorrow, costs $320.  The $1200 is for private room, bed, food, the works.  If you take your own food and sleep in the seat (they're not bad) it's only $320.

Yes, I am aware of rome2rio, but that only has the above options.  The $320 is per way.

What is it exactly that you need that the other options aren't providing?  AFAIK Greyhound and Amtrak can take bikes, and you can probably fly no problem with a bike too.  I don't see an actual problem here

I guess I am looking for something that doesn't exist in the US, high-speed rail, or a bus that runs that route solely, or something else.

Pittsburgh to Denver is about the same distance as Amsterdam to Moscow. I doubt Amsterdam to Moscow, even in normal times, has a direct bus serving it. Train and flying would work about the same.

You've got 4 options listed. You've listed drawbacks (primarily travel time) for 3 of them (train, bus, drive). What's the problem that you're trying to solve for? Without knowing that, it's going to be hard to offer solutions to an unknown problem.

There are no other options at this time other than the above listed. I wanted to explore all possible avenues to compare comfort, cost (both time and money), convenience, etc.

I just searched for PIT-DEN flights, and I see, for example, Frontier asking $78 one-way. Granted, they'd probably charge for checking in the bike (https://faq.flyfrontier.com/help/can-i-bring-my-bicycle-on-the-plane-with-me) but still $400 sounds way off.

Surely there are car sharing websites in the US or you can try hitchhiking, if you're into non-standard transport options. The bike will definitely make things more complicated, but there are lots of pickup trucks in the US where you can simply dump it to the cargo bed.

The distance between Pittsburg and Denver is about 1500 miles (2300 km), hence flying seems to be the only viable options unless you are willing to do an overnight trip (with the associated expenses and/or discomfort).
United operates two non-stop flights on this route per day at reasonable prices and flight times. In mid May basic economy round trip tickets start at around US$300 plus another $80 for the bag/bike. If the bike is properly packed United won't charge you extra for "oversized). See https://www.united.com/en/us/fly/baggage/sports-equipment.html. You may still have to shell out more for your other luggage but that depends on what you are planning to bring. It's cheaper if you have any Star Alliance status.
What about this solution doesn't feel "right" to you? A non-stop bus would still take 24+ hours. A high speed train over that distance would be very expensive and still take a very long time. The distance will make any alternative to flying awkward.

A high speed train from Pittsburgh to Denver would be expensive indeed! First, you'd have to build it! Depending on how the bike is packaged, there will likely be room inside the box for a reasonable amount of clothing (properly protected from the greasy bits), so that might end up being the only checked bag.

This is not an alternative, so it doesn't answer the question.  An answer would be, these are the only options, there are no practical alternatives.
